# Ext JS mvc: how disable button from controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I have a `Ext.grid.Panel` which has a button defined as the following

```
 this.buttons = [ {
            id: 'addInfoBtn',
            text : 'Add Info',
            action: 'createinfo'
        }];
```

What i want to do is enable/disable this button when the screen loads based on a value i am receiving in the controller. I have the following function in the controller that is receiving either `true` or `false` and setting the disabled value to this.

```
,isDisabled: function() {
        var edit = this.getUrlParams('edit');
        var addInfoBtn = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#addInfoBtn')[0];
        addInfoBtn.setDisabled(edit);
        console.log(addInfoBtn);
    }
```

this method is being called when the panel has been rendered by the controller

```
,init: function() {
        this.control({
           'infolist': {
                itemdblclick: this.viewInfo,
                render: this.isDisabled
            }
```

I can see from the console that the value of the `addInfoBtn.setDisabled()` has been set to `true` but the button is still clickable, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the addCommissionBtn = ... a typo?

Comment: Also, you should *religiously* avoid setting id's on your components. Not only are the unnecessary with the availability of itemId and component queries, but they can cause gigantic headaches in your apps if you have conflicting ids.

Comment: sorry yes this was a typo... if i should avoid doing this, what would be the best way of doing this?